# 'from __future__ import unicode_literals' in Django Migrations

Tags: python, django, import, migration

I just want to know that why does every auto-generated Django migration file contains the following line.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

The applications is running fine even if I remove all these lines. So, what's it purpose?

Answer (score 2):

`from __future__ import unicode_literals` makes `"abc"` `unicode` instead of `str` in Python 2.x, so `"abc"` then means the same as `u"abc"` while otherwise `"abc"` would mean the same as `b"abc"`.

For more info see the [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) docs or [PEP 3112](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/) directly.